# Point DNS to Squarespace Except for a Specific Subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, redirect, dns, squarespace

My client is moving their site to SquareSpace, but wants to keep the blog portion hosted in WordPress. I'm not sure what their current hosting plan is, but is it generally possible to point "example.com" to SquareSpace, and have "example.com/blog" still exist as a WordPress site?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done solely through DNS as DNS is ignorant of the path and works only with the domain name. The only way to do this through DNS would be to move the blog from example.com/blog to blog.example.com, then the website can be located on one service at example.com and the blog can still be located on wordpress at blog.example.com.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I suspected, but I just wanted to make sure.